# How to see in chrome developer console a singleton object created in DOJO?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have the following singleton object declared in DOJO.  I would like to know if there is any way to track it in Chrome console, for example with something like `watch` on  `window.mySingleTone`.

```
// App (singletone)
define(['dojo/topic', 'ntv/state', ], function (_topic, _state) {
    return {
        init: function () {
            console.log('app:init');
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "tracking", but Chrome supports the currently experimental [Object.observe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) with which you can "listen" to changes on an object, and might as well log every change to Chrome's console.

Comment: do you know if dojo keep track of this objects?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any tracking mechanisms in dojo, I was just proposing a solution outside of the framework: if you have control over the code which creates the object, then you can attach a change listener to it with Object.observe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to get a reference to the object this module returns, calling `require(mid)` any time after the module has already been loaded will return it.  You should be able to add that as a watch expression, too.